# How do I solve these systems of equations

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

How do I solve the following math problem?

You have an 24 cm long string. Examine if you can cut  in two parts and create

a) Two squares b) Two circles

whose total area is 20 cm². (The entire length must be used)

It says the string is cut into 2 parts, and not 2 equal parts.

So for 2 squares: 
The sum of perimeters will be 24 cm. That's,

$4l_1+4l_2=24$ and

$l_1^2+l_2^2=20$

Similarly, For 2 circles:

$2\pi r_1+2\pi r_2=24$

and $\pi r_1^2+\pi r_2^2=20$

I get 2 equations and 2 unknowns, how do I solve these equations?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a few possibilities for the square case. You can find a solution easily.

Comment: The first equation is linear. You should be able to obtain $l_1$ in function of $l_2$ in any case. Then put the expression for $L-1$ in the second equation and you have a one variable equation, of 2nd degree, that you are able to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that from the first equation (part a) we have $l_2 = 6-l_1$. Now plug the $l_2$ into the other equation: $l_1^2 + (6-l_1)^2 = 20$. This is a quadratic which we solve: $$l_1^2+(36-12l_1+l_1^2)=20 \\ \Rightarrow 2l_1^2 - 12l_1 + 16 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow l_1^2 - 6l_1 + 8 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow (l_1 - 4)(l_1-2) = 0$$ Therefore $l_1 = 2$ and $l_2=6-l_1=4$ or $l_1=4$ and $l_2=6-l_1=2$. That just means one square has side length 2 and the other has side length 4.

You can apply the same method (called **substition**) for the second set of equations.